# k8s - prevent pods to use some service accounts

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I have configured Pod Security Policies on my cluster, which prevents Pods run as root.

However, if any deployment uses a tiller service account, they can start pods as root, basically, they are full admin, no Pod Security Policies restrictions.

Is there a way to restrict which service accounts pods can use?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, it is possible.

You should Bind a Role/ClusterRole.

Example:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-pods
  namespace: default
subjects:
  - kind: User
    name: jane
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: pod-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Nice to read:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

https://docs.giantswarm.io/guides/securing-with-rbac-and-psp/

Comment: How the RoleBinding will prevent Pods to use the tiller service account? I have a default Pod Security Policies to all service account on the namespace, but the tiller serivce account have admin access on the namespace, which not sure why allow Pods to run as root even after blocking with PSP.